# Maximum bound on variance of sample proportion

Tags: statistics

**A poll was conducted to gauge the attitudes
of residents to moose culling. Let p^ be the proportion
who approve of the culling. 
For a given sample size n, what is the maximum possible value of var(p^)
?**

The solution is given as var(p^)$\leq$$\frac{1}{4n}$,
but I cannot find any theorums to support this? 
Does anyone have some helpful suggestions on the theorem used to 
derive this result?

Comment: Is it perhaps because it is a bernoulli distribution and the variance is given by p(1-p)?.

Comment: If sampling is with replacement, the number of successes has binomial distribution, variance $np(1-p)$, so $\hat{p}$ has variance $p(1-p)/n$. The function $x(1-x)$ attains a max of $1/4$ at $x=1/2$. The variance if sampling is without replacement is a little smaller.

Answer (score 1):

The variance of a biniomial distribution with probability $p$ and sample size $n$ is $np(1-p)$ which is maximized when $p=\frac{1}{2}$ as you can see by taking the derivative wrt p and setting the result to 0.  The maximum variance of the number who approve in your sample is $n(\frac{1}{2})(1-\frac{1}{2}) = n/4$.  The proportion is the number divided by n, so to get the variance of the the proportion, divide this by $n^2$ to get $\frac{1}{4n}$ since $\mathrm{Var(\frac{x}{n})} = \frac{1}{n^2}\mathrm{Var(x)}$.